# Unity networking, make player disappear for all clients

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, unet

As title says I need to make the player disappear when he gets in car. Right now, it works as a single-player, but since I am new to unet I don't really know how to achieve this, I tried some ways, but they didn't work. Here is script:

```
 [Client]
 void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
 {
     //so if we hit car
     if(hit.collider.tag == "Vehicle")
     {
         //if we pressed "E"
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
         {
             //call method to disable some stuff taht should be disabled, like: controller, shoot, weapons etc.
             if (isServer)
                 CmdCall(inVehicle, hit);
             else
                 RpcCall(inVehicle, hit);
         }
     }
 }
 [Command]
 void CmdCall(bool invehicle, ControllerColliderHit hit){

     RpcCall(inVehicle, hit);
     }
 [ClientRpc]
 void RpcCall(bool invehicle, ControllerColliderHit hit)
 {

     disable(inVehicle, hit);
 }
```

> *I can't see any errors in console but I cant enter play mode cause there are some compiler errors, which again i cant see in console. thank you for any tip, comment, downvote, upvote, or hint :)*

--Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you call the Command if you are the server, and call the RpcCall if you are not the server. It works the other way around:

- Commands are issued from the **client to the server**.
- RpcCalls are called **from the server to all clients**.

So if you are the server, you should call the RpcCall. And if you are the client, you should send a command to the server, requesting the RpcCall.

Just change:

```
if (isServer)
```

To:

```
if (!isServer)
```

As you are currently using them the other way around.

I'd suggest also suggest, if possible, implement the RpcCall and Command in  the `ControllerColliderHit` class, so you don't have to pass the component as a parameter, which might increase the size of the messages between clients and the server. Also the code would be clearer to read IMO.